#  remove strings in between lines in a file

Tags: linux, perl

I have files that look like:

```
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337  12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646  12.461  -0.386
TER 
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2520 H1  VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
ATOM 2521 H2  VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
ATOM 2522 H3  VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047
```

I have to remove "TER", the line before "TER" and 3 lines after the line just after TER and make file continuous like this:

```
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160   8.337 12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047
```

Comment: You want to delete blank line left from "TER" or what? which "space" ?

Comment: yes the blank line created after removing "TER"..i want to delete that

Comment: This doesnot remove the blank line after removing TER..

Comment: this removes blank lines as you asked, but if you want to remove TER with it's blank line you need something like this  `sed -i '/^TER/d' myfile`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the line which is start with `TER`.

```
   sed -i.bak '/^\s*TER\s*$/d' transrotate/myfiles
```

If you just want to remove empty line, try this:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\s*$/d' transrotate/myfiles
```

Comment: ok now its bit complex..what should i do if i have to delete line before "TER" (ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646 12.461 -0.386) and next 3 lines after the immediate line after "TER".

Comment: @kanika You could do this with sed but it is signifantly more complicated. Can you not use a more powerful tool like Perl or Python?

Comment: @KurtS awk can handle it easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^TER/d' yourFile
```

will do the job

```
kent$  echo "ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337 12.679 -2.487
dquote> ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646 12.461 -0.386
dquote> TER 
dquote> ATOM 2519 N  VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
dquote> ATOM 2520 H1 VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
dquote> ATOM 2521 H2 VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
dquote> ATOM 2522 H3 VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498" |sed '/^TER/d'

ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337 12.679 -2.487
ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646 12.461 -0.386
ATOM 2519 N  VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2520 H1 VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
ATOM 2521 H2 VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
ATOM 2522 H3 VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498
```

**updated based on new requirement**

see the awk line below:

```
kent$  cat t.txt
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337 12.679 -2.487
ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646 12.461 -0.386
TER 
ATOM 2519 N  VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2520 H1 VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
ATOM 2521 H2 VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
ATOM 2522 H3 VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{if ($0~/^TER/)a[NR]=1;}NR>FNR{f=0;for(x in a){if(FNR>=x-1 && FNR<=x+3){f=1;break;}}if(!f){print $0;}f=0}' t.txt t.txt
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337 12.679 -2.487
ATOM 2522 H3 VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498
```

**updated again**

I hope this is the last update:

awk line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if ($0~/^TER/)a[NR]=1;}NR>FNR{f=0;for(x in a){if(FNR==x-1 || FNR==x || (FNR>x+1 && FNR<=x+4)){f=1;break;}}if(!f){print $0;}f=0}' yourFile yourFile
```

test:

```
kent$  cat t.txt
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337  12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646  12.461  -0.386
TER 
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2520 H1  VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
ATOM 2521 H2  VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
ATOM 2522 H3  VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{if ($0~/^TER/)a[NR]=1;}NR>FNR{f=0;for(x in a){if(FNR==x-1 || FNR==x || (FNR>x+1 && FNR<=x+4)){f=1;break;}}if(!f){print $0;}f=0}' t.txt t.txt
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337  12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047
```

Comment: i have to delete line before "TER" (ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646 12.461 -0.386) and next 3 lines after the immediate line after "TER". i.e Lines after the line 
ATOM 2519 N  VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371

Comment: @kanika you should update your question. Those requirements are not mentioned there at all.  Also your output example didn't show it.

Comment: @kanika better yet, ask a new question, as that edit will change the validity of these answers substatially.

Comment: @kanika see my updated awk solution for your new requirement.

Comment: @Eric I posted anew ques for this

Comment: @kanika I know. you actually want to remove the 3rd line after TER, not the 3 lines... right? your expression means 3 lines. I realized that after reading your question, but didn't do the update. :)

Comment: This solution needs to process the file twice and has O(N^2) run time. I still believe a simple Perl or python script would be superior. Though I believe an O(n) algorithm is possible in AWK.

Comment: @kent, I used the updated command as well..It is not working. The lines that are to be deleted are still there. I used on number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force seems to be unpopular this days, but here it goes anyway:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; ($a=<>)=~s!(.*\n){1}TER\n(.*\n)(.*\n){3}!$2!; print $a;' INFILE > OUTFILE
```

The method of course presumes that the input file fits the RAM.

---

P.S. If input is larger than the RAM, then one need a simple state machine. Read file line by line in a loop. `push` lines into an intermediate buffer. If there are more than 4 lines in the buffer, `shift` and print the head. If second line in the buffer is `TER` and buffer contains 4 lines, purge the buffer. Repeat while there are lines.

Comment: The commands seems to delete different lines. It deleted line immediate to TER,whereas i wanted it in the file and keeps 4th line after TER i.e. (ATOM 2522 H3  VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498) whereasthis has to be deleted.

Comment: Indeed there was a little misunderstanding on my part. Corrected. Otherwise, you should really spend some time reading `perldoc perlre` - it is a trove of useful hints and tricks. And the RE above is really a trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

`ed` is great for this kind of thing:

```
$ ed -s file.txt <<EOF
> /^TER/d
> -1d
> +1d
> d
> d
> ,p
> EOF
```

The `p` on the next-to-last line will print the result; change it to a `w` to edit in place and save to the same file.