# perl to remove lines from file

Tags: perl, bash

I have file that looks like:

```
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160 8.337  12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2518 OXT VAL 160 7.646  12.461  -0.386
TER 
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2520 H1  VAL 161 -15.336  5.698 -25.811
ATOM 2521 H2  VAL 161 -13.416 10.529  17.708
ATOM 2522 H3  VAL 161 -14.363  9.436  18.498
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047
```

I have to remove "TER", the line before "TER" and 3 lines after the line just after TER and make file continuous like this:

```
ATOM 2517 O   VAL 160   8.337 12.679  -2.487
ATOM 2519 N   VAL 161 -14.431  5.789 -25.371
ATOM 2523 CA  VAL 161   4.400  9.233  16.454
ATOM 2524 HA  VAL 161   3.390  9.170  16.047
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ remove strings in between lines in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820469/remove-strings-in-between-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: @M42 : It looks like the requirements changed from the question you marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was supposed to write it in Perl, but now I've already written it in Python. I'm posting it anyway as it may prove to be useful, don't see any harm in that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import glob
import os

try:
    dir = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" dir"
    print "Example: "+sys.argv[0]+" /home/user/dir/"
    sys.exit(1)

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, 'File*_*MINvac.pdb')):
    fin = open(file, "r")
    content = fin.readlines()
    fin.close()

    for i in range(0, len(content)):
        try:
            if "TER" in content[i]:
                del content[i]
                del content[i-1]
                del content[i:i+3]
        except IndexError:
            break
    fout = open(file, "w")
    fout.writelines(content)
    fout.close()
```

Edit: Added support for multiple files, like the OP wanted.

Comment: if i run this on all 200 files,what change has to be made?since there are 200 files for 1 system and there are 120 systems..

Comment: @kanika You should've said that in the first post. Are the file names regular?

Comment: Iam sorry for that.. Yes files are named as File10_0MINvac.pdb...File10_60MINvac.pdb.....i.e. File--_--MINvac.pdb is common in all files.

Comment: @kanika I've edited my answer, it should now work with multiple files in a directory if the files have the pattern File*_*MINvac.pdb in their names. I've also tried with a couple of files, as far as I can tell it works.

Comment: @kanika If you've received an answer that works, mark it as an answer so other people can find it easily. I see you've never done that in any of your previous questions, even though you've received answers before.

Comment: @griffin...sure...i think it takes a little time to figure out the working of the forum..

Comment: @kanika 
Read the FAQ, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the part on how to ask questions and how to specify an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple line-by-line script.

**Usage:** `perl script.pl -i.bak fileglob`

E.g. `perl script.pl -i.bak File*MINvac.pdb`

This will alter the original file, and save a backup of each file with the extension `.bak`. Note that if `TER` lines appear too close to the end of the file, it will cause warnings. On the other hand, so will the other solutions presented.

If you do not wish to save backups (use caution, since changes are irreversible!), use `-i` instead.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $prev;
while (<>) {
    if (/^TER/) {
        print scalar <>;  # print next line
        <> for 1 .. 3;    # skip 3 lines
        $prev = undef;    # remove previous line
    } else {
        print $prev if defined $prev;
        $prev = $_;
    }
    if (eof) {  # New file next iteration?
        print $prev;
        $prev = undef;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: You edited my answer to make it unusable on an external file. While this may look better to an experienced user, it is NOT applicable to the OP's question on how to edit an existing file.

Comment: I am a proponent of answers with code one can copy and paste and run. Of course, you can always revert the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @SinanÜnür You could copy/paste my previous code, assuming you added a shebang, and knew to supply the script with a filename argument, and redirect the output. I guess in hindsight, that was a handful of assumptions I made about the OP.

Comment: Yup. If you take a look at the OP's comment to Zaid, even a ready-to-run script wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @SinanÜnür New self-contained version, adapted for multi-file use.

Comment: @sinan I guessed as much, based on your other comments.

Answer (score 0):

So, for each set of 6 consecutive lines, you want to discard all but the third line *if* the second line is a `TER`?

TIMTOWTDI, but this should work:

```
my @queue;
while (<>) {
    push @queue, $_;
    @queue = $queue[2]  if @queue == 6 and $queue[1] =~ /^TER$/;
    print shift @queue  if @queue == 6;
}
print @queue;  # assume no TERs in last 4 lines
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my @array;

tie @array, 'Tie::File', 'myFile.txt' or die "Unable to tie file";

my %unwanted = map  { $_ => 1 }                # Hashify ...
               map  { $_-1, $_, $_+2 .. $_+4 } # ... the five lines ...
               grep { $array[$_] =~ /^TER/ }   # ... around 'TER'  ...
               0 .. $#array ;                  # ... in the file

# Remove the unwanted lines
@array = map { $array[$_] } grep { ! $unwanted{$_} } 0 .. $#array;

untie @array;  # The end
```

Comment: thank you..this runs perfect.I have a question.If i have around 200 files,how can i append the prog to run on all of them..?

Comment: While `Tie::File` is an excellent module, this would not be my recommended solution. It would use a lot of memory if the input has a lot of matching lines.@TLP's solution has a predictable memory overhead of roughly proportional to the length of the longest line. Plus, I would guess it to be faster because it reads input in a linear fashion.