# Perl script to modify file

Tags: perl, jenkins

I have Oracle files that I need to compare to CVS files, but the problem is that there are many files that I want to ignore the first line(s) as part of the diff.  I want to run a script that opens each file, and replaces the file contents in such a way that the final output is replacing `'CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "TRON"."SOME_PACKAGE" IS'` with `'CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SOME_PACKAGE IS'`.  The problem I am having is that the statement can span several lines, so I have to consider a situation like `'CREATE OR REPLACE "TRON"."SOME_PACKAGE" 
 IS'`.

My approach (since this is part of a Jenkins job), is to loop through all the files in the workspace, modifying any files that meet this criteria.  I can then use my existing Perl script that is using `File::Compare` and `Text::Diff::Table`.

I've been testing with [Zaid's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821795/perl-to-remove-lines-from-file) with little success, since it still is not dealing with scenarios where the command string spans multiple lines. (my changes):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;

tie @array, 'Tie::File', 'c:\cb_k_check_recon_mma.sps' or die "Unable to tie file";

my %unwanted = map  { $_ => 1 }
               map  { $_-1..$_-4, $_, $_+2 .. $_+4 }
               grep { $array[$_] =~ /^CREATE.*[IS|AS]$/ }
               0 .. $#array ;

print Dumper \%unwanted;

@array = map { $array[$_] } grep { ! $unwanted{$_} } 0 .. $#array;
print Dumper \@array;

untie @array;
```

Comment: Please don't put `<br>` or `<code>` tags in your text. See [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), for more on Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text can span several lines, for a single regex to work you need to read the file into a string, not line-by-line.

```
perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's/CREATE\s+OR\s+REPLACE\s+PACKAGE\s+"TRON"\."SOME_PACKAGE"\s+IS/CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SOME_PACKAGE IS/g' /path/*.pl
```

The `-0777` switch tells perl to slurp the file, so the regex will only be run once. For that reason, I added the global `/g` modifier, in case more than one substitution per file is needed.

As you see, I use `\s+` instead of space, to match possible randomly inserted newlines. `-pi` in short means to perform in-place edit on the target file(s), and `.bak` after `-i` means to save backups with that extension. It is recommendable to save backups, but not required (except on Windows).

Comment: Wow - I love the simplicity - thank you!  A question:  the actual name to come after 'CREATE OR REPLACE' is relative to the actual file - is it possible to capture the name (SOME_PACKAGE, or PROC_UPDATE, or whatever), and use that as part of the substitution?  (I know this isn't really correct, but something like `code`'s/CREATE\s+OR\s+REPLACE\s+PACKAGE\s+"TRON"\."SOME_PACKAGE"\s+IS/CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE $1 IS/g'

Comment: @T.j.Randall Of course. Whatever is inside parentheses `( ... )` -- capture group -- is captured. `$1` is first group, `$2` the second, and so on. You could use `"([^"]+)"` to capture a quoted string. I purposely removed the entire string to replace it with a new, so that you would not have this problem in the future, but you can tweak it. Problem is if your package names can come in different orders, e.g. `"TRON"."FOO"` or `"FOO"."TRON"`, then it becomes more difficult.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I was working on this last night at home, and I'm hoping you see the error.  Here's my call to replace:  C:\>perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's/ (^CREATE OR REPLACE|\s+)\s*(^[PACKAGE|PROCEDURE|FUNCTION]|\s+)\s*(
\S+)\s*(^[AS|IS]|\S*) / $1 . ' ' . $3 . ' ' . $4/g c:/1_atest/dc_k_b2c_site_sup_u_mma.spb  -- when I run, I'm getting:  '\s+)\s*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  Am I hitting a block with special characters?  Thanks for any pointers!!

Comment: Not sure if @TLP saw my comment by the way I typed it - did my question make sense?  I am messing with trying to add '/' to special characters, to try and resolve.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's quite hard to make out what you are writing there, but that error is a windows cmd error. In Windows, you need to use double quotes for the `-e` code, e.g. `perl -e "print 'foo'"`. `[PACKAGE|PROCEDURE|FUNCTION]` is a nono, you can't put words in brackets `[]`, that's for character classes. And are you trying to join `$1 . ' ' . $3 . ' ' . $4` together by spaces here? That sounds silly, when all you need is `s/.../$1 $3 $4/`. Substitution regex is interpolated, as if inside a double quoted string.

Comment: @T.j.Randall To make it easier on yourself with the Windows shell quoting, just take the regex and put it in a file. Then edit the file in a good code editor like VIM/gVIM, and run it with `perl -pi.bak file.pl target_file`

Comment: ok, will do - thank you for the review! I will move to the file form and run from there.